# Get All Cart Quantity Count In Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to get all cart quantity count but i get error. Might be able to help me? for more details here [Preview](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yedBbp)

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  value = list[i];
  if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
    return value;
  }
}
return undefined;
```

Comment: You didn't provide your products service

Comment: can you tell me, where is it the code?

Comment: Ok Bro Anik, now i get the true. Thanks
If i ask in this case [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yedBbp), can you tell me how to get all cart quantity count?

Comment: Update your question with your current question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in scope

Like this

```
  $scope.totalItem = function() {
    return $scope.cart.map(function(x) {
      return +x.count;
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
  }
```

Now add this method in view

```
{{totalItem()}}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPBxeK)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Bro Anik, I've changed the question. ^_^